# Facing some problem with css @media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

It is working fine when I'm applying it to body color, or changing font-size but when it comes to make element `float` or `flex-direction`, it does not respond at all. Tried in every way possible just not sure what's not working here: please do check the code , I think syntax is proper because it is giving me result as mentioned.

```css
.navbar {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
}

.navbar a  {  
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 24px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    .navbar a {
      flex-direction: column;
   }
}
```

Comment: `a` in your case is a flex child, not flex container, as such it doesn't have `flex-direction` property on itself. If you want to change `flex-direction` change it on the flex-container which in your case is `.navbar`

Answer (score 0):

As @Krusader said, the `a` tag is not a flex container so to use a column layout you need to set it's parent.

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
}

.navbar a  {  
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 24px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    .navbar {
      flex-direction: column;
   }
}
```